# Spring JPA JUnit4 Test Find Entity Not Picking Up New Entity Created With Same Composite Key As Deleted Entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to write integration test(s) for a method that basically works as follows:

```
@Autowired
JpaRepositoryWrapperService service;

@Transactional
public void updateSelections(Integer userId, Integer... choiceIds) {
  service.deleteSelectionsByUserId(userId);
  for (Integer choiceId: choiceIds) {
    service.createSelection(userId, choiceId);
  }
}
```

Tests to verify deleting all previous choices, PASS.
Tests to verify adding any number of choices, with no previous choices, PASS.
Tests to verify retaining one or more previous choices, FAIL.

Notes:

1. The SelectionEntity has a composite primary key of userId and choiceId.
2. Net new SelectionEntity's, are created - it's just those whose composite key matches one that got deleted, that are not re-created.
3. deleteSelectionsByUserId uses a Query annotation - @Query("DELETE FROM SelectionEntity se WHERE se.compositePrimaryKey.userId= ?1")
4. #3 is important because the test passes if I update the method to use the native jpa delete method, and give it both keys.
5. The method works as-is, when ran in my application - just not from my integration test.